# Stability comparison between Acetylene/Ethyne (C2H2) and Nitrogen Gas (N2)

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, enthalpy, stability, valence-bond-theory

N≡N is more stable than H2N—NH2 (hydrazine)

But
HC≡CH is less stable than H3C—CH3

Why is it so? Even though the size of the corresponding compounds and hybridization is the same?
(Usually ethane is reasoned to be more stable than ethyne as : pi bonds are less stable and weaker than Sigma bonds. So hydrogenation inrpoves stability of the hydrocarbon.

But this is the opposite in case of hydrazine... Any explanations? (Perhaps the difference in bond overlap of N—H, N—N & C—H, C—C bonds?))

Why are the two cases the opposite of each other, regardless of the similarities in structures?

Comment: Stable with respect to what?

Comment: All I mean is, why is N2 more stable that hydrazine, whereas C2H2 is less stable than C2H6

Comment: If you say "whereas C2H2 is less stable than C2H**4**" you are almost comparing like with like and talking about stability with respect to hydrogenation. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes! N2 and C2H2 have similar structures. N2H4 and C2H6 have similar structures. Yet the corresponding pairs (N2, N2H4 & C2H2, C2H4) have different relative stabilities... Pretty much the opposite. Why so!?

Comment: Consider bond angles, and number of electrons involved. https://socratic.org/questions/568dc3297c014929be837991 and https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-mcc-organicchemistry/chapter/hybridization-structure-of-acetylene/, for example. Moral: "Like, don't get so bent outa shape and go off an' explode."

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes! exactly my point. Both N2 and C2H2 have a linear geometry yet N2 is stable (way more than hydrazene), whereas C2H2 isn't as stable as its alkane counterpart. Why this difference!?

Comment: It's more subtle that it appears to be. An important factor is weaking of single bonds from C-C to F-F due to repulsion of electron pairs, but

Comment: @Maddy You are on the track of [bond dissociation energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy) $\ce{N#N}$ vs. $\ce{N-N}$, and of $\ce{C#C}$ vs $\ce{C-C}$, and not stability (or reverse: enthalpy of formation) of e.g., acetylene vs ethane -- aren't you?